# is there an Elysian Whip at any point in Fire Emblem: Shadow Dragon?

Tags: fire-emblem-shadow-dragon

I'm going through my first play-through of Shadow Dragon, and I was holding off on promoting Caeda because there may be an Elysian whip to promote her into a Falcoknight.

In the sequel, New Mystery of the Emblem, there's one in chapter 16, but I didn't find one in Shadow Dragon. I decided to promote her anyway but I'm curious if there was one in the first place or if it's only available in the sequel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elysian Whip is available in Fire Emblem: Shadow Dragon, as well as several other games from the Fire Emblem franchise. It first appears in Fire Emblem: Shadow Dragon and the Blade of Light (1990).

In Fire Emblem: Shadow Dragon (2008) can be purchased from the online shop.

You can read more about the Elysian Whip by viewing its [Wikia Page](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/Elysian_Whip)

[image]

Comment: i'm playing on an emulator. can i still access the online shop? cause i'm guessing no...

Comment: Ask it as a new question

Comment: Other information on emulators/online shop [here](https://forums.serenesforest.net/index.php?/topic/11205-any-way-to-get-on-wifi-with-my-emulator/). Be sure to mark this answer as accepted if it answers your question