# Can you access the DS's online shop from an emulator in Fire Emblem: Shadow Dragon?

Tags: emulation, fire-emblem-shadow-dragon

In response to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/357429/is-there-an-elysian-whip-at-any-point-in-fire-emblem-shadow-dragon), I was told that the Elysian Whip can be bought from the online shop. Unfortunately, I'm using an emulator. Can you still access the online shop from there?

Comment: The online shop shut down in 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When playing using an emulator it does not appear that the online shop is accessible. [It appears](https://forums.serenesforest.net/index.php?/topic/11205-any-way-to-get-on-wifi-with-my-emulator/) that the only way to access the online store is when playing the original game or using a [flash cartridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nintendo_DS_and_3DS_flash_cartridges).

In your case the Elysian Whip will not be accessible to you. Sorry about that.